# c++: input of a lambda expression

Tags: c++, lambda

I have the following code:

```
auto x_is_valid = [](const MyX &x) -> bool {
    return x.source != MyXValue::ABC;
};

auto objects = var_.var_in_box(*a, b, c, x_is_valid);
```

I am wondering:

- How is `x_is_valid` computed?
- Where does it take its input parameter?

How do I read this properly?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not being computed, its being passed to `var_in_box`.  You need to look at that code to see how it is used.

Comment: `x_is_valid` is a _functor_, that is, it's an object that overloads the function call operator `operator()`. It can be passed around like any other object. Here's a good read about what lambdas are and how they work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses

Answer (score 2):

A mathematical analogy might help. Imagine a function `f(x) = x^2`.

> How is `f` computed?

It's right there: for any `x`, the formula for computing is `f(x) = x^2`.

> Where does it take its input parameter?

From the caller.

The "answers" above are pretty pointless, but if you understand them in a context of a function in a mathematical sense, they might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If `var_.var_in_box`, expects a `bool` as the last argument, then the call

```
auto objects = var_.var_in_box(*a, b, c, x_is_valid);
```

should result in a compile error.

If the above line compiles without any error, then the last argument type of the above is a callable object, not a `bool`. Presumably, the function uses the passed in callable object to make a function call. It's not possible to determine from the posted code how the callable is called in the implementation of `var_in_box` member function of the class.